# Using Jquery or CSS3 to give the Illusion that a div is growing out of another

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm working on a project where I'm there is an illustration of a map. It's illustrated with a cross section so you can see the earth below it. I want to make it so when the page loads the map looks 2D and then slides upwards to show the cross section 3D. So, what I have done is placed the map underneath a layer (png) that has the negative shape of the map cut out. I'm using jQuery to slide that layer down. But my problem lies int he z-index and the sections of the map getting covered after the animation. Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this effect?

Here is a working page of it so far http://www.gregtaylordesignstudio.com/Great-Lakes-Project/great_lakes_working.html

CSS

```
#topSection {
    width:900px;
    height:749px;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
#base {
    width:900px;
    height:749px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    }


#topOverlay{
    width:900px;
    height:749px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:3;
    display:none;
    }

#mapBack {
    width:900px;
    height:749px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:2;

}
```

HTML

```
<div id="maincontentcontainer">
<div id="maincontent">
  <div id="topSection">
  <div id="base"><img src="images/MAP-backgr.png" width="990" height="749" alt="base_map" /></div>
  <div id="mapBack"><img src="images/MAP-surround.png" width="990" height="749" alt="mapSurround" /></div>
  <div id="topOverlay"><img src="images/MAP-backgr-top.png" width="990" height="749" alt="mapOverlay" /></div>

</div>

</div>    
</div><!-- End maincontentcontainer -->
```

And the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
              $('#mapBack').delay(3000).animate({top:"55px"},600);
        });
```

Comment: Trying to understand the requirement. What do you mean by "the sections of the map getting covered after the animation"? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is...if you look around the edges during and after the animation you can see parts of the white png overlapping the map. I think there must be another way to do this?

Comment: Ok. May have a clearer interpretation now. At the 1st view of the animation, actually did not "see" it, as its duration appears to occur swiftly. One option might be to utilize a `psuedo` element - "on" a single DOM element - instead of an `img`. Then use the `background` property of that `psuedo` element for rendering the "3d" effect. If comprehending accurately, now, the requirement is that no "white" parts are displayed surrounding or "overlapping" the  image?

Comment: Ok. Try without `#mapBack` entirely. Deleted the node at `console` and appeared to display without any portions of the image being "overlapped".

Comment: The problem with doing it without backMap is the map will always appear as 3D. I want it to 1st appear as 2d so the cross section is not seen. Then...have it appear as if it's rising out of the page. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: This can be reproduced at `console` by deleting the `#mapBack` node. Or, if `#mapBack` is essential to the animation, it can be be removed after the animation with something like `$("#mapBack").animation().promise().done(function() {$("#mapBack").finish().detach()})`

Comment: See also the `complete` and `done` `options` available to jquery's `.animate()` http://api.jquery.com/animate/.